# Why code that works on jsfiddle doesn't work locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I take a script from jsfiddle, and obviously it work, but when i try to run it locally, it stops to work. I read in another question that to use jsfiddle code, I need to put my script into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

I do it for the following code, but it doesn't work even. Can someone please help me?

```
<html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
li {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom:3px;
padding: 2px 5px;
}

button {
margin-left: 10px
}
</style>
<script type=”text/javascript”>


 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#btnName').click(function(){
 var text = $('#inputName').val() + '<button>x</button>';
 if(text.length){
    $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.justList')
}
});

$('ul').on('click','button' , function(el){
$(this).parent().remove()
});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="test" id="inputName" />
<button id="btnName">Add</button>

<ul class="justList"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're missing the script tag to include jQuery

Comment: Assuming the error is `$ is not defined`, jQuery is not loaded into your page.

Comment: @AdamAzad: There isn't any error, because of the fancy quotes. Nothing happens at all, making the missing script harder to diagnose.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, indeed, I have missed that! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

1. Because you haven't included jQuery on the page. You need

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
   ```

   somewhere before your `script` (with that path or some other valid path to jQuery).
2. The quotes here

   ```
   <script type=”text/javascript”>
   ```

   are fancy quotes. They must be normal quotes. Or, best practice, just don't include the `type` at all; JavaScript is the default.

It's also worth formatting your code in a reasonable, consistent way.

E.g.:

```
<html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
li {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom:3px;
padding: 2px 5px;
}

button {
margin-left: 10px
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#btnName').click(function() {
         var text = $('#inputName').val() + '<button>x</button>';
         if (text.length) {
             $('<li />', {
                 html: text
             }).appendTo('ul.justList')
         }
     });

     $('ul').on('click', 'button', function(el) {
         $(this).parent().remove()
     });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="test" id="inputName" />
<button id="btnName">Add</button>

<ul class="justList"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```